# "DNS server address couldn't be found" for some websites

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, dns, internet-explorer

So, recently, Chrome (on my Windows 10 laptop) began displaying the error "DNS server address could not be found" (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN) for Facebook, Twitter, Instagram and YouTube.

All other sites work absolutely fine (at least the ones I use and can think of). Firefox and Internet Explorer both spit out errors, too, when trying to connect to these sites. All other computers in my home wireless network don't have this problem, and I don't think it has anything to do with my home network since connecting my laptop to a mobile hotspot still gives me the error when trying to visit the mentioned sites.

I tried clearing the [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)), I tried flushdns, I tried disabling [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) - all to no avail. I ran a full security check on my PC with no results. This is frustrating, and I hope someone can help me!

Oh, by the way, I can still access the websites through the [Tor Browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)#Tor_Browser).

Comment: Well I guess whatever DNS server you're using (your ISP's?) is no good. Try Google DNS or something similar.

Comment: @DanielB I already am using Google DNS...

Comment: Directly or on your router?

Comment: @DanielB I don't know, it works on other devices connected to the router though, so I can't imagine how that would be the problem. Also, accessing the sites on my PC literally doesn't work in any other wireless network either, it's not just limited to my home network...

Comment: You said you are already using google dns. Where have you entered this info?

Comment: @CoscoTech In the Network and Sharing Center under the Connection's Properties. I just entered 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. as the DNS addresses to use.

Comment: Ok. Maybe try something different to rule that out.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to access, say, FB by its IP address: 31.13.66.36?

I put that in my browser address bar and it loads the FB site but I can also load it from www.facebook.com. I'm wondering if you can load it with the IP but NOT the domain name. That would help rule in our out a DNS issue.