# Chrome gets stuck on "server DNS address could not be found" if I tried to access a domain while connecting

Tags: google-chrome, dns

This happens to me quite a lot, and I'd like to know if there's a way to prevent it or a better way to fix it than restarting my computer. The circumstances are very different to existing questions like [“DNS server address couldn't be found” for some websites](https://superuser.com/questions/1116083/dns-server-address-couldnt-be-found-for-some-websites); it goes like this:

1. I turn on my computer (Windows 8.1) and internet router (which is either a 3G mobile router that I'm waking up from sleep, or a normal wireless router and modem that isn't on all the time because I'm in a country where there isn't power all the time)
2. I connect to the internet, see the "connected" icon show and open a web page...
3. ...however, I sometimes misjudge it slightly, and try to access a web page a second or two before the router has completely finished starting itself up. It gives this message in Chrome:

   > **This site can’t be reached**
   >
   > some.domain.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
   >
   > `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

   ...with "reload" and "details" buttons, neither of which do anything.

   This is fine, it's presumably because I attempted to access a web page before the router/modem hadn't yet fully connected to the internet.
4. **The problem is**, it then gets stuck for this domain:

   - Any attempt to access this domain then gives the same error, even after I'm fully connected and can access any other site
   - Other domains work fine, and this domain works fine in other browsers (e.g. Firefox)
   - Closing and re-opening Chrome doesn't fix it
   - Toggling whether the domain uses https or www. doesn't make any difference

For example, just now, I tried to open a web page slightly too early, and Chrome's DNS got stuck. I'm writing and posting this question in Chrome, in a different tab, and it's working fine. I still can't open that other web page in Chrome, but I can in Firefox.

It's like it only tries once, caches the result, and won't retry even if I use the "reload" button on the error page. Sometimes the domain works after a long period of time (30 mins?)

Is there any simple way to make it retry the DNS that is more convenient than rebooting the computer or waiting a long time?

Comment: Does using `control+F5` make any difference? Restarting Chrome should fix the problem unless there is any other Chrome related proccess in background. Hace you tried to delete the cache?

Comment: Don't know how to delete the cache; I'll try ctrl-F5 next time it happens thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting your DNS cache.  Since you mentioned Windows 8.1, I will provide instructions for Microsoft Windows.

`#`1: Get to a command prompt.  If you're using UAC (likely), get to a UAC-elevated command prompt.  (So, find the icon for your command prompt, and choose "Run As Administrator".)  I've used the CMD command prompt more often, but I would expect PowerShell to work just as well.

`#`2: Run: ipconfig /flushdns

You can also use the GUI to repair the adapter, but that does some more stuff which is typically unnecessary.  (So, that is slower.)  If you find the above steps too tedious to do regularly, consider making a batch file so all you have to do is to run an icon (double-click on the desktop, or have in your Quick-Launch bar.)

If that doesn't work, try using the GUI to repair your network connection.  When it asks you about resetting the adapter, see if you get good results by saying yes.  If so, that may be quite tedious, but still better than a full reboot.

Comment: What if this helps but only **temporarily**? After a while all is broken again. Where to check?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem recently and after calling at technical support, I resolved the issue by changing the port in which I had the cable going to the PC, at the router. The 4th port wasn't working, so I plugged the internet cable in the 3rd port...
Now it works.

Answer (score -1):

type this on your chrome address bar :

chrome://net-internals/#dns

and then click the "clear host cache" button.

load the problem webpage again, 90% of the times it works, if not do as the first answer in this post tells you.
good luck!